# RST request sent to the remote host after I send a SYN and receive a SYN-ACK

Tags: networking, tcp, stack, ip

I am currently developping a TCP/IP stack ; I am running under Linux and I use libnet (for transmitting) and libpcap (for capturing Ethernet frames ) to simulate the link layer.

I have started to work on TCP, more specifically on the active opening of a connection. Basically, I send a SYN packet, the remote host responds with a SYN-ACK which I must acknowledge by an ACK. The problem is immediately after I receive a SYN-ACK, a RST packet is sent to the server, probably by the kernel, not by my own program anyway. I think the packets captured by libpcap and analysed by my  network stack are also captured by the kernel who doesn't understand why he has received a SYN-ACK packet from a host he never tried to connect to and thus sends a RST to cancel the connection.

So basically, the connection is reset while it has even not been established, making it difficult for me to  try other tests.

How could I solve this problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a firewall rule with iptables which will prevent the kernel from answering to your connections. libpcap gets the packets before the firewall denies them so you can still read them and respond to them yourself.